# php curl loop till status is completed

Tags: php, rest, curl

Hi I have a request which returns a xml response.
The status can be "INPROGRESS" or "COMPLETE"
Sometimes u need to run the request just once to get all results and status Complete, but for new searchterms u need to re-run it a couple of times depending how many result texists on the fileserver.

```html
<entries>
<meta>
<id>5eccddef7e3c2c1694003622</id>
<status>COMPLETE</status>
</meta>
</entries>
```

It's a search api which needs to be fired a couple of time till status is "COMPLETED" in stead of "INPROGRESS"
Since users won't do that i need the curl to loop till status is completed prior to showing entries/results of the search query.

```html
function call_curl() {
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxx.xxx.nl:8443/core/dosearch?searchstring=".$_REQUEST['keyword']."&searchloc=/pdf/&searchscope=0&searchresulttype=files",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  
     ));
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
return $response;
    }
```

how do i run the function till status is "completed" in the most efficient way in terms of execution time and cpu load?

Comment: you can call `curl_exec($curl)` multiple times, each time you call it, it will execute it again, If the output is static in length, a substring and compare will be the most efficient, a regex is also somewhat efficient, but the most reliable is xml parsing, but its te slowest. maybe adding a sleep 1  or usleep(100000); will give your cpu some rest

Comment: i did something like 
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($response);

while ($xmlObject->meta->status == "INPROGRESS") {
if ($xmlObject->meta->status == "COMPLETE") {
die;
}
}
but that seems to loop forever

Comment: $status = "INPROGRESS";
$teller = 0;
while ($xmlObject->meta->status == "INPROGRESS") {
  $data = call_curl();
  $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($data);
echo $teller;
$teller++;
}

This is working, only thing is it takes 30+ requests to finish where normally it takes 3 or 4 times max if i just execute them manually